# Understanding the matching propensity score

Tags: r, propensity-scores, matching

I am currently using the package PSweight from R to do propensity score with 2 different methods : IPW and Matching.
I first used it to make a propensity score based on IPW method to get the average treatment effect (ATE), but then i also tried the matching method and i am wondering if i should chose between one or another, or if it's a good thing to show the results of both methods.

Additionnally i am not exactly sure how the matching one is done. For example if in my treated group i have 35 patients and 65 in my control group, it will compare to the 35 closest matching weights out of the control group ? And so it would be only 70 patients involved in the effects results instead of the 100 for the IPW

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.